# how can i resolve the native binary dependence in VS Code plugin development , such as swc and esbuid

Tags: vsix, swc, vscode-plugin

I'm writting a VS Code plugin.

Some command is compile the code and bundle js. I use esbuid and swc in my case.

I'm not sure that if should I bundle the native dependences in my plugin，or put them as project npm dependences.

The plugin will support all operator system, like macOS、Windows ,etc.

if I bundle this , the plugin size will be too big?

How to resolve this problem？